# Symfony Expression Validation

Tags: php, symfony, expression

How can I add custom function to symfony expression validator. For example, I wrote these expression: `"value in array_keys(this.getValues())"` and want adding array_keys function.

I created custom expression language class

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\ExpressionLanguage;

use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionFunction;
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage as BaseExpressionLanguage;

class ValidatorExpressionLanguage extends BaseExpressionLanguage
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function registerFunctions()
    {
        parent::registerFunctions();

        $this->addFunction(ExpressionFunction::fromPhp('array_keys'));
    }
}
```

but still got error.(

Comment: You should edit your question and put your source code in the question's body instead of that [image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```
validator.expression:
  class: Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\ExpressionValidator
  arguments:
    '$expressionLanguage': '@App\ExpressionLanguage\ValidatorExpressionLanguage'
    tags:
      - { name: 'validator.constraint_validator', alias: 'validator.expression' }
```